# Create Unix Timestamp in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I create a unix timestamp in MySQL? I know the type is set to `INT` and value is `NULL` but I need it to populate with current time in the format like: 1343782742

Comment: You really could have Googled this

Comment: I thought code help was for **code help**

Comment: Sure, if you show an effort. We're not here to do your work for you, though

Comment: clearly your not here to help anyone with negative post - sometimes when something is new to a person, they just need a little help... sorry to have bothered you.

Answer (score 9):

use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)`

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/6346)
- [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

Comment: Why use `CURDATE()` and not `NOW()`?

Comment: actually I want it to store it in the database in that format on record creation?

Comment: @JeffB the one I showed you was `SELECT`, you need to use `INSERT`, example, `INSERT INTO tableName (colName) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()))` . you can add more columns and values if you want.

Comment: I think i'm asking my question wrong... I want the field within the database to auto pupulate with the current datetime when a record is inserted. I have a 'timestamp' field in th database, if i set the TYPE to DATETIME and DEFAULT to CURRENT_DATE that will work, but not in unix format.

Comment: I need the value stored in the DB as an INT not DATETIME in that format, I have hundreds of pages reading from that format in other DB i'm moving to new, so I need to keep in same format, where all new records get created with that field auto populating in unix datetime format.

Comment: I guess you need to create `TRIGGER` here.

Comment: ok thanks, i'll have to rethink this one... I'm not up on TRIGGERS

Comment: you need to create `AFTER INSERT` triggers.